# Implement blocking control flow in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to create a blocking control flow, but have hit a dead end.
The idea is that a request comes in and flows through a number of handler functions. Each function does something and decides whether or not the request is now fulfilled. If it is, the handling stops, if not, the next handler is invoked.
Each handler might or might not do something asynchronously (like fetching/writing data). If that is the case, then the following handlers depend on the data being there before being started.

So far, I have two ideas, which both do not quite match these requirements:
1) All handlers are functions, which are pushed into an array and iterated over with `some` . If a handler wishes to stop the control flow, it simply needs to return `true`.
With this approach, I can't have any of the handlers invoking asynchronous functions.

2) All handlers are promises which are chained. This seems like a better idea to me, but I can't figure out how to best handle stopping the control flow. I have two ideas:
- Keep a variable which is set to `true` once a handler decides to interrupt the flow. Check this value in every single handler and resolve immediately, if needed. This means a lot of duplicate code.
- Rejecting a promise if it does not wish to continue the normal flow, and continuing in `catch`. However, the thought of using errors as a means of controlling the flow pains me - and also it means that I have to handle the case where the catch is invoked because of an actual error.

My spidey senses tell me there has to be another way, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Some Promise implementations, like `bluebird`, offer [promise cancellation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/cancellation.html).

Comment: Basically, you are asking looking for the either monad.  Which promises more or less are.  I'd recommend [this talk](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/), though it's node specifically.  For a practical answer, I think using reject to stop the flow is fine.  There is nothing that dictates that it means "an error", that's just a semantic convention

Comment: typo after edit limit: above should have said _not_ node specifically...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't chain the promise handlers, nest them. You can do that programmatically from an array of functions:

```
var handlers = […]; // functions that can return promises

var run = handlers.reduceRight(function(next, handler) {
    return function() {
        return Promise.resolve(someArg).then(handler).then(function(result) {
            if (result) // true, whatever
                return result;
            else
                return next();
        });
    };
}, function end() {
    return Promise.reject(new Error("no handler matched"));
});

run().then(function(result) {
    // the result from the first handler that returned anything
}, function(err) {
    // some handler threw an exception, or there was no handler
});
```

Comment: I admit that I have a hard time wrapping my head around this code. So far, I can not get a handler to fail, even when explicitly returning false, and after every handler has been called, the end() function is also called, throwing the error. Is the result in the if statement the same as the function argument (res)?

Comment: @PhilippFlenker: Ah, yes, typo in the parameter name. When a handler returns `true` it should stop, when it returns `false` it should continue with the `next` (literally), and when it throws it'll go straight into the `catch` callback.

Comment: ok, it seems that I made a mistake adapting your solution. I want the handlers to take an argument (the same in all cases). It seems to work without the parameter. Do you have a suggestion on how to make it work with a parameter (like handler(param) )?

Comment: I checked your solution and it solves my problem, thanks! Now all I have to figure out is the parameter thing...

Comment: @PhilippFlenker: I've put `someArg` into my snippet that will be sent to the `handler`

Comment: This is a perfect use case for ES6 Generators!

Comment: @Sukima: You mean generators used as a substitute for proper `async`/`await`?

Comment: I bearly read the question. But I did see the us of `next()` in the answer and that got me to think that instead of chaining the handlers declaritivly perhaps a generator could take an ordered list of promise producing handlers and chain them one at as they resolve or reject. I looked like that was what the above answer suggested only with out the generators. Newer syntax for simular functionality. In other words a promise producing generator where the resolution of the last promise would return the next promise or null (ending the flow). Maybe I’ll write an answer later I’m driving now.

Answer (score 5):

You can use ES6 generators to generate the promises as needed. Each time a promise resolves it could check for a stop value and if false (i.e. continue to the next handler) ask for the next from the iterator.

```
function* promiseHandlers() {
  const handlers = [
    promiseHandler1,
    promiseHandler2,
    promiseHandler3,
    promiseHandler4,
    promiseHandler5
  ];

  for (const handler of handlers) {
    yield handler();
  }
}

function run(iter) {
  const i = iter.next();
  if (i.done) {
    return Promise.reject(new Error("end of iterator reached"));
  }
  return Promise.resolve(i.value).then(result => result || run(iter));
}

run(promiseHandlers());
```

This isn't actually chaining though. Instead it would execute each promiseHandler in order but the results of those are not passed to the next. I think this is correct for what the OP wanted especially since a truthy result ends the iteration (i.e. break).

Comment: Indeed some things were missing :-) I hope you don't mind the edit.

Comment: This recursive function is indeed a bit better than my approach, as it's more performant not to build the whole "chain" before the execution. That way it also works for open-ended iteration - it's more like a `while` loop than a `for of` loop - which is nicely depicted with the generator that could be infinite.

Comment: Don't roll your own coroutines! You're missing a bunch of cases. Mind if I make your `run` more "compliant"?

Comment: @Bergi In what case the rejection would be reached in this code?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: `run` in this case was not thought to be a coroutine runner (especially none that passed the last result back), but a recursive asynchronous function that traverses a promise-returning iterator until it finds a truthy value. Maybe `runUntil` would've been a better name. Or maybe `findAsync` with a predicate?

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo: The `Promise.reject` is met when the iterator runs out of handlers, when we reach its end without having found one promise that fulfilled with a truthy value.

Comment: @Bergi Just what I was thinking. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, that looks very good and helped me learn about generator functions. What does `result => result` do?

Comment: `result => result || run(iter)` is equivalent to `function (result) {return result || run(iter)}`. Read up on ES6 arrow function syntax. Using arrow functions will help you cut down dramatically on the amount of typing you need to do in order to realize the same functionality, and they can also help you write more easily readable code.

Comment: How is this a coroutine? And of so, why are coroutines bad to make? What does “more compliant” mean? Was that comment a troll? I know I’ve read documentation on using generators to generate promises. How is this bad?